# Reverse Geocoding example doesn't display the street name of a location in some regions

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

[This reverse geocoding code](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse) does not return the street name of a location in some areas (Example: {36.82687, 10.09948}), actually, I get only the name of the town and the country despite the fact that the name of the street is available on the map. I was wondering if there was a trick to get the streets' names in those regions?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you provide an example that demonstrates the issue? Does the "0th" result have a street name?

Comment: Yes, I just added the latitude and longitude in my question : (36.82687, 10.09948)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you reference returns the formatted_address of the 2nd entry ("[1]") in the results array.  The most detailed entry is usually the 1st entry ("[0]").  If I change the code to use that, I get the street name.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/pyqxgtqt/)

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: {
      lat: 40.731,
      lng: -73.997
    }
  });
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

  document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
    geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow);
  });
}

function geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow) {
  var input = document.getElementById('latlng').value;
  var latlngStr = input.split(',', 2);
  var latlng = {
    lat: parseFloat(latlngStr[0]),
    lng: parseFloat(latlngStr[1])
  };
  geocoder.geocode({
    'location': latlng
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      if (results[0]) {
        map.setZoom(11);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: latlng,
          map: map
        });
        infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
        map.setCenter(latlng);
      } else {
        window.alert('No results found');
      }
    } else {
      window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
    }
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
#floating-panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 25%;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'sans-serif';
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
</style> <style> #floating-panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -180px;
  width: 350px;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
#latlng {
  width: 225px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="floating-panel">
  <input id="latlng" type="text" value="36.82687, 10.09948">
  <input id="submit" type="button" value="Reverse Geocode">
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
```

If you really only want the street name, you should not depend on the entry in the results array, you should iterate through the results of the first (most exact) entry, looking for the `address_component` with type `route`

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/pyqxgtqt/2/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var marker;

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: {
      lat: 40.731,
      lng: -73.997
    }
  });
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(evt) {
    geocodeLatLng(evt.latLng, geocoder, map, infowindow);
  });
  document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
    geocodeLatLngForm(geocoder, map, infowindow);
  });
}

function geocodeLatLngForm(geocoder, map, infowindow) {
  var input = document.getElementById('latlng').value;
  var latlngStr = input.split(',', 2);
  var latlng = {
    lat: parseFloat(latlngStr[0]),
    lng: parseFloat(latlngStr[1])
  };
  geocodeLatLng(latlng, geocoder, map, infowindow);
}

function geocodeLatLng(latlng, geocoder, map, infowindow) {
  geocoder.geocode({
    'location': latlng
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      if (results[0]) {
        map.setZoom(15);
        if (marker && marker.setMap) {
          marker.setMap(null);
        }
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: latlng,
          map: map
        });
        map.setCenter(latlng);
        // find the street name of the first entry
        var street_name = "not available";
        for (var i = 0; i < results[0].address_components.length; i++) {
          for (var j = 0; j < results[0].address_components[i].types.length; j++) {

            if (results[0].address_components[i].types[j] == "route") {
              street_name = results[0].address_components[i].long_name;
              break;
            }
          }
        }
        infowindow.setContent(street_name);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      } else {
        window.alert('No results found');
      }
    } else {
      window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
    }
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
#floating-panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 25%;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'sans-serif';
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
</style> <style> #floating-panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -180px;
  width: 350px;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
#latlng {
  width: 225px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="floating-panel">
  <input id="latlng" type="text" value="36.82687, 10.09948">
  <input id="submit" type="button" value="Reverse Geocode">
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: It works, thank you for your answer. Out of curiosity, do you know why it works using the "1st" result in some areas : (40.714224, -73.961452)?

Comment: In some areas the second entry is the road, you can't depend on the index in the results array.

Comment: Okay, thanks, in my case the first code is perfectly adequate.